# How to use methods of a wildcard class<?> result

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

I am trying to build a generic tool that finds a hibernate class and uses its methods by means of metadata.

So from the database I get 1: "TABLENAME" 2. "methodname"

Step 1. Finding the hibernate is done.

```
Class<?> result = generator.getClassFromTableName("TABLENAME");
```

Step 2. using the methods that are in the class that is returned is something I do not get.

Do i need to use classloader or finding it through result.getConstructors?

Easiest would be if I end up with an instance of 'TableName' and be able to acces all its methods. Hope it is clear!

Comment: I suggest you read up on [reflection](https://www.baeldung.com/java-reflection)

Comment: I did see that guide but I get stuck at Bird bird = (Bird), for me that is not possible. I only have the classname and method. result(parameter).methodname().

Comment: Bird bird = (Bird) in section 8. Generic invoking an objects constructor with parameter and its method is where I get stuck

Comment: If you do not have access to (or upfront knowledge about which) type of class you are loading an implementation of, you fall back to `Object` as type and you can call the methods via the reflection API. If you do know which interface is implemented by the class you can use the interface name in place of `Object` or the class type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @rsp for the reassurance to look within Reflection. First time to dive into it and in the end it was pretty straightforward.

- Classloader to load class from string parameter
- getConstructor to
  find the right constructor and use it with newInstance()
- getDeclaredMethod to find the right method and use it with Invoke and
  the object instance

  ```
   Class< ? > testdataClass = getClass().getClassLoader().loadClass(testDataClassname);
   Constructor<?> tesdataClassConstructor = Objects.requireNonNull(testdataClass).getConstructor(datacontext);
   Object testdataClassObject = tesdataClassConstructor.newInstance(dc);
   Method buildMethod = testdataClass.getDeclaredMethod("build");
   return buildMethod.invoke(testdataClassObject);
  ```